# Css flexbox conditional wrapping

Tags: css, flexbox

I have a skinny list that I'm showing in a resizable panel. The items in the list itself are dynamic (not known before hand and generated using "ng-for" directive in angular).

The panel I'm showing the items in can be resized to pre-set which is a factor of some min-width. So let's say the min-width is 100px, the user can resize the panel to be 200, 300 or 400px.

The way I need to style it is a bit complex and I'm wondering if it's even possible.

1. If the panel is min width (100px) show the items in a single column with vertical scroll if list overflows max height (300px). (in the example below, you've to scroll to see the 3rd item)

> |item1|
>
> |item2|

---

> |item3|

2. If the user resizes the panel and increases the width, on overflow, the items should start wrapping.

> |item1| |item3|
>
> |item2|

I was playing around with flex box and wondering if I can conditionally set the flex-wrap property.

Comment: Yes you can set `flex-wrap: wrap | nowrap | wrap-reverse`

Comment: set a `flex-basis` of say 100px for the *flex items*?

Comment: @MariosNikolaou, yes, I can set the `flex-wrap` property, but is there a way to do that conditionally? I don't want it to wrap if the panel is smallest (100px wide), in that case I want the items to overflow and show a scrollbar